# Pinch Zoom whole Custom GridView with its component

Tags: android

I have an android app with Custom grid view (every grid contains 3 textviews).
In Base adapter i set all array elements to the text view and Inflated customized xml layout to every grid.
Its kinda custom list view and each box contains 3 textview but it looks like a table with 6 columns.

Now i want to pinch zoom my whole table including its sub custom layout.

i tried to put my gridview in framelayout and used **ScaleGestureDetector**
for framelayout
i tried this code https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602.
It only works for single child level and could not get width of child in gridview.

i am new to android please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Add**
    ZoomView zoomView=(ZoomView)findviewbyid(R.id.zoomView);

[zoomview.jar](https://android-zoom-view.googlecode.com/files/android-zoom-view.jar)

Comment: @user2393336 you can google it, easily available. Check github link for more info https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view